# Event listener for end of video

Tags: video, adobe-edge

I have a symbol button that starts to play a video (but and video are on frame 1 of the root timeline).

I would like the timeline to go to frame 2 (and show some text) at the end of the video.

Please can someone help point me in the right direction?
I would be most grateful.